# didReceivelocalNotification is never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilocalnotification

I am tired of doing this. Let me tell you whats happening. I am using iOS 9.0 & Xcode 7.3.1.

**Situation 1 :**

I have registered for local notification settings in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like this.

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound] , categories: nil)
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
```

I have several controllers in my project, user will be pressing one button in one of these and I will be scheduling a notification by calling a function in `App Delegate`. The function is given below.

```
func activatingUserLocalNotification(timeIntervalSinceNow : NSDate?, alertBody : String, userInfo : [NSObject : AnyObject], region : CLRegion?)
{
    let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = timeIntervalSinceNow
    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotification.alertBody = alertBody
    localNotification.region = region
    localNotification.regionTriggersOnce = false
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNotification.userInfo = userInfo
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
}
```

Now I have set a notification by pressing on a button, which called this above function it successfully scheduled the notification.

I have set breakpoints in all these methods.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {
        // Break Point
        return true
    }

func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, withResponseInfo responseInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    // Break Point
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    // Break Point
    }

 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceivelocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification)
    {
    // Break Point
    }
```

And waited for sometime while the app is in `Foreground`, Waited some more time. Nothing happened. I thought the app would fire up the notification and one of the method would get called, so that I could present the notification inside the app. But nothing happened.

**Situation 2 :**

Now I have tried the same, now I minimised the app [ **App is in Background state** ] by going to an another app and using it for sometime. Now the notification fired up properly, just like I have told you I have set breakpoints in almost all methods but none of them called when I clicked on the notification. But it called `applicationWillEnterForeground`, What am gonna do with this method without the `launchOptions`.

It's been two days I am fighting with this, Don't have any idea about whats happening.

**Push Notifications Works Fine Though [ Inside & Outside the App ]**.

Let me know your thoughts? Please.

How I call this function `activatingUserLocalNotification`  from a controller.

```
 func setLocalNotificationForDistance(id : String, name : String, location : CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius : Double)
    {
        let alertBody = "Hello \(name)"
        let dict : [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["aps" : ["alert" : alertBody], “id” : id]
        let region = CLCircularRegion(center: location, radius: radius, identifier: id)

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.activatingUserLocalNotification(nil, alertBody: alertBody, userInfo: dict, region: region)
    }
```

**App Delegate**

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//
//

import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import SVProgressHUD
import Alamofire
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    //MARK: Local Variables

    var window: UIWindow?

    static let UpdateRootNotification = "UpdateRootNotification"
    static let ShowMainUINotification = "ShowMainUINotification"

    //MARK: Application Life Cycle

    // Did Finish Launching

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {

  let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound] , categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

        return true
    }

    // Foreground

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {


    }

    // Did Become Active

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 // clear badge icon
    }

    // Did Enter Background

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    }

    // Opened Via Shortcut

    func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem
        shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {

    }

    // Continue User Activity

    func application(application: UIApplication, continueUserActivity userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: ([AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

        return true
    }



    //MARK: Local Notification

    func activatingUserLocalNotification(timeIntervalSinceNow : NSDate?, alertBody : String, userInfo : [NSObject : AnyObject], region : CLRegion?)
    {
        let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.fireDate = timeIntervalSinceNow
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
        localNotification.alertBody = alertBody
        localNotification.region = region
        localNotification.regionTriggersOnce = false
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        localNotification.userInfo = userInfo
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, withResponseInfo responseInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], completionHandler: () -> Void) {


    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {


    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceivelocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification)
    {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

         UIApplication.sharedApplication().presentLocalNotificationNow(notification)

    }

    // MARK: Push Notification

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

        if API.sharedInstance.isLoggedIn() {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(deviceToken, forKey: "push_token")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

            API.sharedInstance.registerDeviceToken(deviceToken)
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        EventTracker.trackEventWithCategory("APN", action: "Registraion", label: "Failed")
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        APNSManager.sharedInstance.handlePushNotification(userInfo)
    }

    //MARK: Open URL

    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL:url,sourceApplication:sourceApplication,annotation:annotation)
    }

}
```

Comment: Please share your app delegate swift file code as is.

Comment: Thanks, please show code that calls "activatingUserLocalNotification"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit funny, but change:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceivelocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification)
```

To:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification)
```

Note the capital L. From docs:

[image]

Also: expect this delegate method to be called only when your app is active. No notification should be visible in that situation as your app is active. You can handle it by using didReceiveLocalNotification delegate method.

Comment: Let me check & come back.

Comment: You are the Man :) Thanks a lot.